# How to grant or revoke lake formation by boto3 for IAM groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-lake-formation

I'm trying to use AWS lake formation to perform grants and revokes of permissions for AWS IAM groups, via console I can normally, but via Boto3 or AWS CLI I get an error stating that IAM groups are not accepted in these actions.

[ERROR BOTO3 IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyPjm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Groups aren't principals and can't be granted permissions using resource-based permission policies.  If your Group and your LakeFormation stuff are in the same account, you should attach your LakeFormation permissions to the Group rather than using a resource-based permission policy.  If they are in different accounts, allow the Group members to assume a Role from the LakeFormation account and give permissions to that.